# Adding #! to jQuery Address

Tags: ajax, jquery, hash, web-crawler

I'm using the jquery address plugin and now my URLs are like `http://localhost:3000/#/users/1/`. I want it to use `#!` instead of just `#` according to the guidelines at http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html.

Here's my JS:

```
$('.likable').find('a').click(function(e) {
        $.address.value($(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '').replace('http://'+document.domain,''));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.ui-show').find('.close').live('click', function(e) {
    history.back();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Setup jQuery Address Listener
    $.address.init(function(event) {

        if ($.address.baseURL() != 'http://' + document.domain) {
            if (location.href.indexOf('#') < 0) {
                // URL has no hash value and is a permalink, e.g. /about/
                // Change address value to that of permalink
                var fullpath = location.href.split('/',4);
                $.address.value(fullpath[3] + '/');
            }
        }

    }).change(function(event) {

        if (event.value != '/') {
      $.get($.address.value(),function(data) {
        // Insert new content
        });
        } else {
            // Remove new content
        }

    });
```

How do I use `#!` instead of `#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.address.crawlable(true);
```

using that in your init event makes all the `#` be `#!` automatically, I loaded mine in a `$(document).ready` event

I hope this helps other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace the instances of `#` with `#!`.